# Helidon serve static content

Tags: jax-rs, helidon

I would like to server static content from my Helidon MP server. But I only get `No handler found for path: /static/index.html`.

I have [configured the static resources](https://helidon.io/docs/latest/#/mp/jaxrs/04_static-content) in `src/main/resources/META-INF/microprofile-config.properties`:

```
server.static.classpath.location=/static
```

And I [start my server](https://helidon.io/docs/latest/#/mp/guides/03_config) with:

```
Server.builder().config(Config.create()).build().start();
```

I guess I have to add an JaxRsApplication? But how do I do that?

I figured out it does work when I use the `io.helidon.microprofile.cdi.Main` but I want to manually create the server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a config issue, you are using `io.helidon.Config.create()` which doesn't support `microprofile-config.properties`.

If you use `Server.create().start()`, `microprofile-config.properties` will work out-of-the-box.

If you want to pass your own instance of config, you can do it like this:

```
Server.builder().config(ConfigProvider.getConfig()).build().start();
```

This has the same effect as `Server.create()`.

---

If you want to use the Helidon config API, you can convert an instance of `org.eclipse.microprofile.config.Config` to `io.helidon.config.Config` like this:

```
io.helidon.config.mp.MpConfig.toHelidonConfig(ConfigProvider.getConfig())
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a module for serving static content called **helidon-webserver-static-content**:

https://helidon.io/docs/v2/apidocs/io.helidon.webserver.staticcontent/io/helidon/webserver/staticcontent/StaticContentSupport.html

Here are some examples:

https://www.tabnine.com/code/java/classes/io.helidon.webserver.StaticContentSupport